# tkinter: 'Button' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a button with this script

```
b1 = Button(root,
        text="1",
        width=10,
        command=lambda:add("1","1")
        )
```

the add function is as follows:

```
def add(symbols,real):
    with open("equation.txt","r") as f:
        equationreal = f.read()
        
    with open("show.txt","r") as f:
        equation = f.read()
    
    out.insert(END,real)
    equationreal += symbols
    equation += real

    with open("equation.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(equationreal)

    with open("show.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(equation)

    print(equationreal)
```

Every time I press the b1 button, it throws this error:

> command=lambda:add("1","1")
>
> TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable

I have tried numerous different approaches to this, even making a function that calls the add("1","1"). Every time I think I have the line that is causing this to break, it changes. Any help?

Comment: I don't see anything in this snippet that looks wrong. I'll bet somewhere else in your code you used "Button" as a variable name. If not, show us a [mcve].

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is this line: b1.place(x=80,y=300)

Comment: The error means that you have declared a Button named `add`.